# How to disable auto-escaping of HTML entities in php \SoapClient?

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client, html-encode

I have to talk to a remote remote SoapServer that has a string field `MessageXML` where I have to put in unescaped XML that is encapsualated in CDATA.

I am trying to use php's default `\SoapClient`.

My `$payload` looks like this:

```
<![CDATA[<DepartureDate>01/12/2015-01/12/2016</DepartureDate>]]>
```

Yet when requesting the Soap service via:

```
$client->ThatMethod(['MessageXML' => $payload];
```

I can see that the actual response gets escaped in the process via:

```
$lastRequest = $client->__getLastRequest();

string (1055) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/SOAP_SERVICE"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:ThatMethod><ns1:MessageXML>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;DepartureDate&gt;01/12/2015-01/12/2016&lt;/DepartureDate&gt;]]&gt;</ns1:MessageXML></ns1:SearchBySea></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"
```

I do realize that this is expected behaviour, yet it seems that the Soap remote cannot handle escaped data. This is why I don't want to escape the payload.

How to set the parameter that it accepts raw unescaped data?

Comment: I worked around the issue by dropping the SoapClient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138345/how-to-change-soapaction-http-header-for-soapclient?lq=1

Comment: No way to do it with SoapClient?...

Comment: @Lionel I haven't found any even though I find the issue odd. Yet since I use guzzle, I don't miss the soap client at all. In the end, you can just talk HTTP with a soap api.

Comment: yep, i saw your guzzle solution, but it's not a good one for me... have you seen that? https://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/659779-soapclient-escaping-xml-tags

Comment: @Lionel No, I haven't. If any of the described methods there worked for you, please add it as an answer.

Comment: My problem has evolved since i'm not obliged to use "cdata's not escaped data", so i've no time to test these solutions, the next guy perhaps!