# How to change SOAPAction HTTP header for \SoapClient?

Tags: php, http, soap, http-headers

I have a rather nitpicky SoapApi that I want to talk to.

I need to change the `SoapAction` header that is sent with the HTTP request.

I am not talking about `\SoapHeader` that is passed along with the Soap Envelop as part of the XML message, but the HTTP header `SOAPAction`.

Using curl I would send the request like this:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/my-custom-action" --data @message.xml http://some-soap-endpoint.asmx --proxy le-proxy:3218
```

It seems one can only set the SoapAction during `SoapClient` creation

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using `\SoapClient` and for this particular "Soap" API ([for a different reason as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521051/how-to-disable-auto-escaping-of-html-entities-in-php-soapclient)) used Guzzle instead simply mimicking the curl request.

There, I fired a simple post request with raw XML against the API, and now it is working; even though I think it's a downside of not being able to use the dedicated `\SoapService`.

If one wonders how to send a XML requests via guzzle, one can do:

```
$options = [
    'body'    => $body,
    'headers' => [
        "Content-Type" => "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        'SOAPAction'   => 'tempuri.org/my-custom-action',

    ],
    'proxy'   => 'tcp://le-proxy:3128',
];
$client = new Client();
$soapRequest = $client->createRequest(
    'post',
    "http://some-soap-endpoint.asmx",
    $options
);

try {
    $response = $client->send($soapRequest);
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    /**
     * error handling
     */
}
```

I consider this a workaround though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exakt same problem with an API. I was simply not able to set the SOAPAction header the way the API needed it. Then I found a page stating to set the SOAPAction in the __soapCall() as an option:

```
$soapClient->__soapCall(
        $name,
        $arguments,
        ['soapaction' => 'someAction'],
        $soapHeaders,
        $soapOutputHeaders
    );
```

In my case Zend2 was not forwarding any options since it states "Options are already set to the SOAP client object". So I had to overwrite the __call function to forward this option correctly.